# What is the range of the function std::arg()?

Tags: c++

I am using the `<complex>` C++ header, and need to know the range of the `std::arg` function which returns the phase angle of a complex number. Ie, is it [-pi, pi], [0, 2*pi], or something else? Is there a guarantee about the range in the standard?

AFAICT, `std::arg` basically just wraps `atan2`, which I think guarantees the range is [-pi, pi]. Is this true of all compliant implementations of C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of `std::arg()` doesn't really provide much detail (26.4.7 [complex.value.ops] paragraph 4):

> ```
> template<class T> T arg(const complex<T>& x);
> ```
>
> Returns: The phase angle of `x`, or `atan2(imag(x), real(x))`.

The definition of `atan2()` is in the C standard (7.12.4.4) which specifies in paragraph 4:

> The `atan2` functions return arctan `y/x` in the interval [−π , +π ] radians.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will tread carefully and not make any assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/

Return Value
Principal arc tangent of y/x, in the interval [-pi,+pi] radians.

So, if `std:arg()` gives the `atan2` response, as its supposed to, you should get what you hope for on any compliant system.